# Registering phoneline to Ozeki Voip SDK blocks phone ringing

Tags: c#, windows, voip, ozeki

I'm using `Ozeki.VoIP.SDK` to handle incoming VoIP calls in our Elastix system. What I'm trying to do is to read and show information about incoming calls in my application **and** let the desk phones ring too.

The problem is when I **register a phone line** from VoIP pool to Ozeki controller, **incoming calls to that line will no longer ring on my desk phone**. But when I un-register that phone line, my desk phone rings again when it receives phone calls.

I have no idea why Ozeki SDK blocks the calls I'm reading in my application.

```
    private ISoftPhone _softphone;
    private Dictionary<string,IPhoneLine> _phoneLines;

    public Softphone()
    {
        _softphone = SoftPhoneFactory.CreateSoftPhone(IP_ADDRESS, MIN_PORT, MAX_PORT, SIP_PORT);
        _softphone.ChangeNATSettings(Ozeki.Network.Nat.NATTraversalMethodType.NONE, "", "", "");
        _softphone.IncommingCall += softphone_IncommingCall;
        _phoneLines = new Dictionary<string, IPhoneLine>();
    }
    public bool IsRegistered(string username)
    {
        return (_phoneLines.Keys.Contains(username));
    }
    public void Register(SIPAccount account)
    {
        if (IsRegistered(account.UserName))
        {
            Unregister(account);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        //throw new Exception(string.Format("The account with username={0} already registered.", account.UserName));

        // With the SIP account and the NAT configuration, we can create a phoneline.
        IPhoneLine phoneLine = _softphone.CreatePhoneLine(account);
        // If our phoneline is created, we can register that.
        _softphone.RegisterPhoneLine(phoneLine);

        _phoneLines.Add(account.UserName, phoneLine);
    }
    public void Unregister(SIPAccount account)
    {
        IPhoneLine phoneLine = _softphone.CreatePhoneLine(account);
        _phoneLines.Remove(account.UserName);
        _softphone.UnregisterPhoneLine(phoneLine);
    }

    private void DispatchAsync(Action action)
    {
        var task = new WaitCallback(o => action.Invoke());
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(task);
    }

    private void softphone_IncommingCall(object sender, VoIPEventArgs<IPhoneCall> e)
    {
        DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            onIncomingCall(e);
        });
    }
    private void onIncomingCall(VoIPEventArgs<IPhoneCall> e)
    {
        if (IncomingCall != null)
            IncomingCall(this, e);
    }
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before? I have no clue.

Comment: Who is your VOIP provider?

Comment: @mjwills we are using elastix

Comment: Does https://www.elastix.org/community/threads/multiple-registration.130199/ help?

Comment: @mjwills thank you very much. This link seems to have the answer

Comment: What specifically was the answer for you? Can you add it below for the benefit of others?

Comment: @mjwills sure I will as soon as I make it work myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the link mjwills mentioned, I found out this was a known behavior of VoIP systems and its workaround is **to define one followme line for each line** and make the application register **only to the followme lines** and not the lines registered by desk phones.